# Бинарная запись в файл

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте! Можно ли организовать бинарную запись в файл также как текстовую? Например:

```
ofstream file("new.txt", ios::binary);
file << "Hello, World!" << endl;
file.close();
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не используйте `форматирование кода` для выделения названий, ключевых слов и т. п. Это форматирование предназначено для идентификаторов в коде и коротких отрывков кода. Названия, ключевые слова и тому подобное обычно никак не должны выделяться. **Если автор пожелает**, он может использовать курсивное или полужирное начертание. См. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@egordorichev](/users/26699/egordorichev),  в винде (насколько помню) есть только пара отличий между бинарным и текстовым файлом  (причем они реализуются не на уровне языка C++, а где-то в системных библиотеках ввода-вывода):

- в текстовом файле символ ^Z (код 0x1a hex, 26 dec или 032 oct) при чтении интерпретируется как конец файла (EOF)
- символ `\n` при записи заменяется на пару символов `\r\n` (конец строки), а при чтении наоборот признак конца строки `\r\n` заменяется на `\n`

В остальном эти типы файлов не отличаются.

Comment: А под маком, кстати, `\n` меняется на `\r` при записи и наоборот при чтении.

Comment: Да, [до версии 9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_9), а тут [описание Newline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) в разных ОС.

Comment: @avp: Хм, и правда. Но XCode до сих пор предлагает сохранить в одном из трёх форматов (`LF`, `CR`, `CRLF`).